# Google Cloud IoT Core quick start

Tags: google-iot-core

I am trying to run step by step [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart).

And an error text with several large logs being shown on screen, as below:

Google Cloud IoT Core MQTT example:

```json
    error { '0': {},
    '1':
    { [Function: require]
     resolve: [Function: resolve],
     main:
      Module {
        id: '.',
        exports: {},
        parent: null...
```

I am using ES256 private key created IoT device and registries as specified in the quickstart guide.

My question is NOT [this one](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/cannot-get-google-iot-core-to-work), as the logs are different.
Mine  says "error" instead of "connect"

Comment: The closest one I found that seems success logs, mine are error logs https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/cannot-get-google-iot-core-to-work

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of [Cannot get Google IoT Core to work](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/cannot-get-google-iot-core-to-work)

Answer (score 3):

This error can be caused by the `--cloud_region` being incorrectly or not specified. For example, here is the command line taken from the Quickstart guide with the `--cloud_region` added for `europe-west1`.

```
node cloudiot_mqtt_example_nodejs.js \
    --project_id=PROJECT_ID \
    --registry_id=my-registry \
    --device_id=my-device \
    --cloud_region=europe-west1 \
    --private_key_file=rsa_private.pem \
    --num_messages=5 \
    --algorithm=RS256
```

Answer (score 2):

My best bet is to look [their own troubleshooting manual](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/troubleshooting) because the Google Iot Cloud is in so early beta that there is no proper error handling / tracing available and as an outsider I can only guess what is wrong with that little log snippet.

API there is changing and the procedure to establish connection is quite lengthy so places of error may be many. Thus more precise instructions cannot be given based on this information.

Comment: agree with you, anyway I used clean environment to build up from ground to get it working now. Looks like an issue of access management